# find the value of psudo class variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey every one I want to alert value of n from this string

```
$('.orbit-bullets:has( > li.active:nth-child)');
```

Comment: What value of n? Not sure how that selector will work when you are not specifying the index `jQuery(':nth-child(index/even/odd/equation)')`

Comment: yes I want to know the integral number of n from this string

Comment: In my markup I get a unordered list having a number of children li , I want to know which child do have class "active"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the index of a `li` with the class `active` inside an element with the class `orbit-bullits` you could do something like this:

```
$('.orbit-bullets>li.active').index()
```

this will return a 0-based index